# How to pass file location in batch file

Tags: c++, batch-file

I'm currently trying to create a batch file that has a file location pass to it within c++.

`$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)`

^^ that variable currently holds the files location. So if you run 
`Command cmd(TEXT("$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"));` it opens the file explorer to that files location.

Now I am creating a batch file, by doing

```
const char* batch_file_name = "filelocation.bat";{

std::ofstream batch_file(batch_file_name);
                batch_file <<
                    "set path_location=%1\n"
                    "%path_location%\n"
                    "cd %path_location%\n"
                    "pause\n";
            }
```

`system("filelocation.bat " + TEXT("$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"));`

That is how i'm trying to pass in the files location. Seems to throw an error though "expression must have integral or unscoped enum type". I've been trying to figure this out, but I'm am stuck. Any ideas to the solution?

Comment: `$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)` does not parse to anything in C++ or a batch file.  Your question is confusing.  Please take the [tour], read [ask] and do post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

`"filelocation.bat " + TEXT("$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"` is trying to concatenate two string literals (of potentially different types, depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined or not). That will not work.  Try this instead:

```cpp
system((string("filelocation.bat ") + "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)").c_str());
```

Or:

```cpp
system(("filelocation.bat " + string("$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)")).c_str());
```

Or:

```cpp
ostringstream oss;
oss << "filelocation.bat " << "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)";
system(oss.str().c_str());
```

Or, simply don't concatenate at all:

```cpp
system("filelocation.bat $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)");
```